# All I have is a Tibco.EMS.dll, what else do I need?

Tags: c#, .net, tibco, ems

All I have is a Tibco.EMS.dll version 5.1.4.0 for .NET, what else do I need?

Anyone know where I can download a manual?

Do I need anything else like like other DLLs or config files?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I think it is clear if you know anything about TIBCO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on what you are trying to do.  We also have the Tibco TEMS DLL which is the WCF extensions for EMS.  This allows you to configure you endpoints directly in Web.config file of your hosted service or in the app.config of you app.

If you have a tibco login you can log into http://download.tibco.com   and download the documentation (Release notes code examples etc) if you want just documentation on usage you can probably go to https://docs.tibco.com/

Answer (score 2):

1) TIBCO EMS Server should be installed for you to communicate with. + TIBCO Runtime should be installed.
2) For my c# client TIBCO.EMS dll is enough, nothing else.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not precise at all about what you are trying to do, or what you expect from your dll.

But, if you have a dll (supposing you trust the origin of it), why don't you add it to a project references, and try to discover what classes and methods this file offers you?

Comment: Anthony, nrocha is right.  This site is about answering questions, and your question is too broad to expect a specific answer.  Being rude isn't going to help you get blood from a stone.

Comment: No it isn't. I am asking about a very specific piece of software which will be used in a specific way. I think the accepted answer proves this doesn't it?

Comment: @Lerxst I think you mean too "Specific" not broad. If you know specifically  about Tibco and it's DLLs you can answer the question. As the other two answers prove.